# Magento 2.4.3 :- After login Dashboard page is not loading in Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.4.3

I have install magento 2.4.3.  But i have getting this error in console.

`Access to font at 'http://localhost/m243/pub/static/version1628682058/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/fonts/opensans/regular/opensans-400.woff2' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

**How to solve this issue ?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a billow line in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue with the CORS policy, so you need to make the following changes:

- Run this command in your terminal:

  `Sudo a2emod headers`
- To add the CORS authorization to the header using Apache, simply add the following line inside either the `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>` or `<VirtualHost>` sections of your server config (usually located in a *.conf file, such as httpd.conf or apache.conf), or within a .htaccess file:

> 

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

- Then simply restart the apache server:

> apache2 -t

> systemctl restart apache2.service

For more info:
https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html